# Change view action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have two views setup link together, and the one is a webview and the other a basic menu view. If I go to the webveiw I have a loading splash display. (Using SVProgressHUD for the loading splash. ) If the user hits, the back button to the menu view, the loading splash will stay on screen until the web view loads, is there a way to kill the loading splash when the user hits the back button.

Answer (score 0):

`SVProgressHUD` has a `dismiss` method.  You could call that in your View Controller's `viewWillUnload` method.

[SVProgressHUD documentation here](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD)